# EntityState in update?

Tags: codefluent

What is the correct approach while updating a record in CFE ?

We are using webapi controllers, based on [this link](http://blog.codefluententities.com/2013/02/27/using-asp-net-web-api-with-codefluent-entities/), the client-side is developped thanks to AngularJS.
I am having troubles updating a record that already exists and my code fails with an CodeFluentDuplicateException.

I read [here](http://www.softfluent.com/product/codefluent-entities/knowledge-center/unique-contraint-failes-because-codefluent-does-not-delete-child-first-in-composition-relationship-) that EntityState shouldn't be changed manually. When I want to update a server version with the client changes, shall I consider:

- Taking the server version and then applying changes made by client ?
- Ask the client version to Save() ?
- Any other approach ?

Thanks for your answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CodeFluentDuplicateException` means that you are inserting a record that already exists in the database. This occurs when the stored procedure executes an `INSERT` statement instead of an `UPDATE`.
CodeFluent Entities don't use the `EntityState` to choose whether the entity must be created or updated in the database. Depending on your model, it uses the `RowVersion` property (insert if `null`; update otherwise). If there are no way to choose, the stored procedure executes an UPDATE and when no rows are updated it inserts the row. For instance:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Role_Save]
(
 @Role_Id [uniqueidentifier],
 @Role_Name [nvarchar] (256),
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF(@_rowVersion IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    UPDATE [Role] SET
     [Role].[Role_Name] = @Role_Name
        WHERE (([Role].[Role_Id] = @Role_Id) AND ([Role].[_rowVersion] = @_rowVersion))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Role] (
        [Role].[Role_Id],
        [Role].[Role_Name])
    VALUES (
        @Role_Id,
        @Role_Name)
END
```

So in your case I would check the code of the generated stored procedure to understand why it tries to insert the record instead of updating it.

In fact you can change the `EntityState` manually if you need to, but there are only a few reasons to do it.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable return, it would surely help me on the long run